# Convergence of the series from the exponential integral $E_1(z)$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I am solving for the expansion of the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma (0,z)$. I have arrived at the following:

$$\Gamma (0,z) = \int_z^\infty e^{-x} x^{-1} dx = E_1 (z) = \int_1^\infty e^{-xz}x^{-1} dx$$

where $E_1(z)$ is the exponential integral. I also know that this is equivalent to

$$E_1(z) = -\gamma - \ln z - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^n}{n n!}. $$

What I would like to know is if there is any way that the series in this equation can be expanded or its convergence solve such that it is equal to $z + O(z^2)$ where $O$ is the error approximation of the series towards infinity. That is, I need to have

$$E_1(z) = -\gamma - \ln z + z + O(z^2). $$

I also know that the series is a Taylor expansion of some function but I do not yet know what this function is nor if it converges to $z$.

I am quite new to all this and am having a hard time piecing all the information. I would very much appreciate any help. I am using the 1972 Handbook of Mathematical Functions and Arfken, Webber, and Harris's Mathematical Methods for Physicists as references.

Comment: Can you see that the series converges for all $z$?

Comment: @Gary, yes according to the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series converges for all complex $z$ by the ratio test. Then write
$$
 - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{z^{n} }}{{nn!}}}  = z - z^2 \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{z^{n - 2} }}{{nn!}}} .
$$
If $\left| z \right| \le K$ with some $K>0$, then
$$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{z^{n - 2} }}{{nn!}}} } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{K^{n - 2} }}{{nn!}}} \le \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{K^{n - 2} }}{{(n-2)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{K^n }}{{n!}}}  = {\rm e}^K,
$$
i.e.,
$$
 - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{z^{n - 2} }}{{nn!}}}  = z + \mathcal{O}(z^2 )
$$
on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hi @Gary, sorry for asking, how exactly is $O(z^2)$ expanded? I just know what it should be but not its formula. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: @user1178472 Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "expanded"? I showed that the infinite series after the first term, which is $z$, is of order $z^2$ on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$. If I just give you $\mathcal{O}(z^2)$ you cannot expand it, it is just some a function which is bounded by a constant times $|z|^2$.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1178472 Would you mind upvoting and accepting my answer?

Comment: I already did but I am new so I need at least 15 reputation first

Comment: @user1178472 It seems that voting requires 15 rep but accepting does not: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/332043